# How can i upload html5 bootstrap theme to odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have odooo online account, how can i import bootstrap theme purchased on themeforest, in the odoo? or what i should do to convert current normal theme to be working with odoo?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add the css file and the js-script file to your assets_common. Odoo will then minimise all the CSS and JS Files into one (or slightly more) files. 
In addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml you can see how the built in bootstrap is added in odoo.
So if you want to add something to all of the javascript files you can do it like this:

```
    <template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend" name="<name of your addition>" priority="15">
        <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<path to your js file>"</script>
        </xpath>
```

But adding a CSS or JS that isn't built for odoo might cause problems since selectors might be overwritten or you use different bootstrap versions.

I havent't tried it with Bootstrap Themes myself so there might be better solutions.